# Click Event does not get fired in SPFX Extension in IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have created one spfx extension of type application customizer. I have attached click event to setting icon span.But when I click on setting icon it does not get fired.

This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox,IE edge but not working in IE 11,

Following is the code..

```
 const settingIcon = document.getElementsByClassName(SETTINGS_ICON)[0];
  if (settingIcon != null) {
    settingIcon.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    alert('Hi')            
  });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, maybe provide a screenshot of your console in IE? that would help us solve your case :)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code in a spfx extension and it works well in IE, the click event get triggered.

[image]

Test demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/app-extension/README.md

BR

Answer (score 0):

IE11 doesn't support arrow functions. Use `function` instead.

```
var settingIcon = document.getElementsByClassName(SETTINGS_ICON)[0];

if (settingIcon != null) {
  settingIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('Hi');
  });
}
```

Comment: tried..but didn't work